# Why is window.innerHeight incorrect until I tap? Chrome (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, google-chrome

When I view this page in Chrome on my mobile phone:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-au">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="position:fixed;bottom:0;right:0;background:#f00;width:50px;height:50px">
        </div>
        <div id="output">
        </div>
        <script>

setInterval(() => document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = `windowHeight: ${window.innerHeight}`, 37);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

On first load, it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of appearance on first load]

And after tapping once on the page (anywhere), it changes to:

[image: Fixed appearance after tapping once]

You can see from the red box that this also affects the positioning of `position:fixed` elements on the page. This was the start of my investigation, and I've pared down the page to get to this point, but can't work out what I'm doing wrong!

This only happens for me on Chrome (Android), on my mobile. I've also tested in the responsive view of desktop browsers and I can't get it to happen. I'm running Chrome version 111.0.5563.116 on my mobile and it's a Huawei Y9 Prime 2019.

It also only happens on a fresh tab. If you load the page, tap once, then reload the page, the page will keep the right `window.innerHeight` when reloaded.

I've listed all these details because I'm fearing it may be some weird browser bug. Is it a bug? Is there a workaround? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you could make your code into a runnable snippet (use the <> in the editor) it will be easier for people to test on their mobile devices. Are you holding the phone in portrait or landscape orientation?

Comment: I didn't have much luck replicating the problem inside a snippet (the page has already been tapped once at that point), but I've put it inside a snippet anyway. I'm holding the phone in portrait orientation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Changing the flags, or changing settings in the browser is not a good practice when developing a website, because most of the users don't change flags, and/or don't change their browser's settings, or customize them that much. If they do, they are aware of them. And so, for the website to work for everybody, you should develop under the browser's state/condition as it is, out of the box - downloaded, as is, in a mint condition for a standard circumstance/environment to be for development.

I'm using 112.0.5615.47. and I couldn't replicate the issue.

If you tap on the screen and it zooms in, it means that it is interpreting the tap as that (a zooming in), it can't distinguish it from pinch out, that's why it decreases the viewport, but on simple load not, it remains larger (and on tapped smaller).

A workaround could be to disable the resize function with the `user-scalable` to `no` on the meta tag, like so

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no">
```

Be aware that the no-resize technique is meant for responsive web pages. If your pages are not responsive, then you should NOT disable user resizing; doing so could render your pages impossible to read on smaller devices.

Further reading: https://wp-mix.com/disable-resizing-meta-viewport/

> Disabling resizing should be avoided for accessibility reasons. --
> [A Haworth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10867454/a-haworth)

<strike>**Second EDIT:**</strike>

If a double tap(?) causes a zooming, a workaround would be to disable that, which is not the same as disabling the scale, no bad accessibility issues.

This code will basically just prevent the double tap feature from happening. The event is still triggered for every touchstart event, so just put any other functionality outside of that if statement and you'll be free of the annoying double tap zoom feature.

```
var time_stamp = 0; // Or Date.now()
window.addEventListener("touchstart", function(event_) {
    if (event_.timeStamp - time_stamp < 300) { // A tap that occurs less than 300 ms from the last tap will trigger a double tap. This delay may be different between browsers.
        event_.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    time_stamp = event_.timeStamp;
});
```

Related post: [How to disable double tap zoom feature in Chrome 30 on Android (Nexus 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789951/how-to-disable-double-tap-zoom-feature-in-chrome-30-on-android-nexus-10)

I assume that your phone is outdated, that's causing the issue.

**Third EDIT:**

I now tried to replicate the issue on a phone that has Android 10 (because that is the latest version that the Huawei Y9 Prime has - according to [gsmarena.com](https://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_y9_prime_(2019)-9742.php)) installed on, and I can still not replicate the issue.
So, it's still an open question what causes the issue.

**Fourth EDIT:**

Apparently, based on **[Bojan B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6345400/bojan-b)**'s comment (

> Got similar issue, but with the usage of the fullscreen API on Android Chrome 113. Going fullscreen produces a larger than expected result and it is corrected as soon as we touch the screen. The same code used to work fine for years, so we suspect it is something related to updates. The issue only occurs in portrait and the values on the Galaxy S8+ are all over the place. Screen height is supposed to be 846; initial fullscreen sets itself to innerHeight 813, and after tap, it corrects to 769.

) the issue is caused by an update, so it's some kind of bug, so, a workaround must be applied, specifically to that version.

Comment: Disabling resizing should be avoided for accessibility reasons.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I upgraded to Chrome 112 and still had the same problem, but your confirmation you couldn't replicate the problem gave me some guidance. I downloaded Chrome 113 (beta) and couldn't replicate the problem with the beta. I tried signing out of my account, but that didn't change things. I finally bit the bullet and deleted all of Chrome's (now v112) data + cache, and magically everything started working. I suspect I might have toggled some setting (maybe in flags) to change Chrome's behaviour.

Comment: Oh, and maybe needless to say, but the `user-scalable=no` didn't change anything either.

Comment: I still haven't worked out entirely what causes the problem for me, but it seems after resetting Chrome if I just change one of the flags in chrome://flags (I changed "smooth scrolling"), the problem starts occurring. Reverting the flag doesn't seem to fix things, and I'm resorting to resetting Chrome to get the right behaviour back. Very strange.

Comment: A bit of an update. I know this answer is accepted, but it seems it's still a mystery as to why this is happening. Indeed, on a fresh download of Chrome, it doesn't happen, but even without changing flags, something *changes* after a period of time and I start experiencing the issue. Just wanted to throw this in for anyone stumbling across this official answer. I still don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I've started a bounty. I hope that someone will answer this properly, or at least better than me. Cheers!

Comment: I've updated my answer. Have a look.

Comment: iorgv, what makes you think it causes zooming? Look at the size of the text in both screenshots. Also, there's no double tapping. Vendor of the phone is Huawei. It's a Huawei Y9 Prime 2019.

Comment: Got similar issue, but with the usage of the fullscreen API on Android Chrome 113. Going fullscreen produces a larger than expected result and it is corrected as soon as we touch the screen. The same code used to work fine for years, so we suspect it is something related to updates. The issue only occurs in portrait and the values on the Galaxy S8+ are all over the place. Screen height is supposed to be 846; initial fullscreen sets itself to innerHeight 813, and after tap, it corrects to 769.

Comment: I'm still seeing this issue in Chrome 120 in android. Where I'd expect 770, I can see that `window.innerHeight`, `window.visualViewport.height` are both quite far off with 1082, and `screen.height` is 892. This still requires a single tap or other interaction on the screen for it to fix itself.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem too and it took me three days to fix it. The reason for this is that Chrome for Android counts the height of the keyboard when calculating `window.innerHeight`.

Add `interactive-widget=resizes-content` to your `meta` tag viewport:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, interactive-widget=resizes-content">
```

See:

- [Get viewport height when soft keyboard is on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023549/get-viewport-height-when-soft-keyboard-is-on)
- [Prepare for viewport resize behavior changes coming to Chrome on Android](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/viewport-resize-behavior?hl=en)

Answer (score 3):

#### Case: `width=device-width, initial-scale=1`

- In fullscreen mode, the value before a single tap exceeds `screen.height`.
- In fullscreen mode, the `innerHeight` value after a single tap becomes 26px smaller than `screen.height`.
- After a single tap, the values of `innerHeight` and `screen.height` do not match, and curiously, the screen height is confirmed to be `774px`.
- To accommodate this, set the fullscreened element's height to `screen.height - 26px` (*1)(*2).

| Property / State | Default | Fullscreen | Fullscreen & 1 Tap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `innerHeight` | 670 | 822 | 774 |
| `outerHeight` | 670 | 822 | 774 |
| `screen.height` | 800 | 800 | 800 |
| `screen.availHeight` | 800 | 800 | 774 |
| `documentElement.clientHeight` | 670 | 822 | 774 |

#### Case: `width=device-width, initial-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover`

- In fullscreen mode, the `innerHeight` value after a single tap becomes equal to `screen.height`.
- Simply set `screen.height` as the height of your fullscreened element(*2).

| Property / State | Default | Fullscreen | Fullscreen & 1 Tap |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `innerHeight` | 670 | 848 | 800 |
| `outerHeight` | 670 | 848 | 800 |
| `screen.height` | 800 | 800 | 800 |
| `screen.availHeight` | 800 | 800 | 800 |
| `documentElement.clientHeight` | 670 | 848 | 800 |

#### Conclusion

By specifying `viewport-fit=cover` in the viewport meta tag, the issue can be simplified. With this specification, after making an element fullscreen and then tapping the screen once, its height will match `screen.height`. Therefore, if you apply CSS to fit the fullscreened element and set the height to `screen.height`, you can layout within an element of the correct height. However, please be aware that there are separate issues associated with `viewport-fit=cover`.

(*1) A comprehensive investigation regarding device differences has not been conducted.
(*2) Be mindful that fullscreen elements on smart devices may not accept height changes. In such instances, it is necessary to specify the height for the child element of the fullscreen element.

Comment: I would like to point out that if you use `dvh` units in your css, in my test cases, they have the same value as `window.innerHeight` so that may cause size differences between `100dvh` and `screen.height`